# How to access images from Ubuntu command line on Windows directory?

Tags: command-line, mount, windows, files

My command is:

```bash
./build/bin/FaceLandmarkImg -f "./mnt/c/Users/topgu/Desktop/Test/sample7.jpg"
```

I'm trying to implement the OpenFace tool on my own image but it's not working. I first tried by pasting it in the OpenFace folder but that did not work. I then decided to access it from Linux on the Ubuntu terminal through Windows - but I still get the error:

```bash
Error: Could not open the image: ./mnt/c/Users/topgu/Desktop/Test/sample7.jpg
```

Can anyone help with this? I'd be more than happy to answer any further questions if you are not understanding what I am asking.

Comment: The path should probably begin `/mnt/c/Users/` (without the leading `.`)

Comment: If @steeldriver's suggestion doesn't work, then I recommend you **[edit]** this question with the output of `mount`.